# Playing with animation in android

Tags: android, animation, graphics, delay, wait

i am just learning android animation and thought of playing with it.
i have created animation but i want that there should be delay/wait between animation.

here is code.

```
new AnimationUtils();
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
findViewById(R.id.app_logo).startAnimation(anim);
findViewById(R.id.addTopic).startAnimation(anim);
findViewById(R.id.addDescription).startAnimation(anim);
findViewById(R.id.addBtn).startAnimation(anim);
```

now i want that after `findViewById(R.id.app_logo).startAnimation(anim);` it should wait for animation to finish. once its finished `findViewById(R.id.addTopic).startAnimation(anim);` should start and so on.

If any can guide me on how to achieve it i would be happy thankful

Thanks.

Comment: you can use animation listener or you can also use animation set..to play animation one after other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple solution to your needs:

```
    final Animation anim0 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
    final Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
    final Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
    final Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
    Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            switch (count){
                case 0:
                    findViewById(R.id.addTopic).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.addTopic).startAnimation(anim1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    findViewById(R.id.addDescription).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.addDescription).startAnimation(anim2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    findViewById(R.id.addBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.addBtn).startAnimation(anim3);
                    break;
            }
            count++;

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    };
    anim1.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    anim2.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    anim3.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    findViewById(R.id.app_logo).startAnimation(anim0);
    findViewById(R.id.addTopic).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.addDescription).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.addBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not i wanted. in this it shows all my widget and then one by one they animate. I don't want that brother.

I want the app_logo animation, then addTopic and so on. I want one by one not all at once.

could you help me another code..???

Thanks

Comment: So just define their invisibility to GONE in xml or runtime and add above each one                     findViewById(R.id.the_view_the_now_you_want_to_show).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: works like charm. Thanks brother.
but i have doubt, why cant we put findViewById(R.id.app_logo).startAnimation(anim); inside a case in switch statement..?

i tried putting inside case 0: but i won't animate.

and why do we need to start animation of app_logo outside the onAnimationEnd..??

Sorry to eat your head but i am just learning and curious to know

Comment: because the listener listen to events. If the animation won't trigger by start animation on the first View the onAnimationEnd() never will call

Comment: thanks for all your help. with your code, the animation are showing one after the other but only the app_logo animation is started every time other animation starts

i.e 1st app_logo animation.
2nd addTopic animation with app_logo animation. and so on

Comment: It strange. Maybe you putted         findViewById(R.id.app_logo).startAnimation(anim);
 inside the AnimationListener by accident?

Comment: yeah it is strange. Its out side the listener as u have stated above.

Comment: so just add     findViewById(R.id.app_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE); inside case 0

Comment: i tried but if i put visibility gone of app_logo in case 0 then i only show me app_logo animation and all other are not visible.

Comment: tried your code but didn't work. It only show app_logo animation not any others animation.

Comment: there must be a simple and small problem which we are not able to figure it out.
and also can you help me with my another problem. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160923/deleting-records-which-are-generated-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

this link will solve all your problems

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations